# Q&A, and Blog Site - Keep to one table or split to 2 or 3 tables?

Tags: database-design

Working on an idea for a Question/Answer/Blog site. For the content of each of these, I can store them all in one table with some columns applying or not applying to each of these different types with a type column to differentiate each - OR, I can separate them into two tables Question/Blog, and Answer (or other combo), or into 3 tables one for each type.

In the one table idea, the columns would look like: id / heading / detail / type / qid

type column would differentiate each by being 'question' / 'blog' / 'answer'

qid would reference the id of the question for Answer

QUESTION: uses heading, detail, type

BLOG: uses heading, detail, type (qid matches question, if assigned as an answer, but not typical)

ANSWER: uses detail, type, qid (qid matches question id, does not use heading column)

There may be another column or two (not shown) that may apply to one type and not the other.

I think storing all in one table may make queries simpler where there is a relationship between them, but the table gets much larger quicker... What is a good approach to a database/table design like this with the expectation this community can grow quite large over time (10K to 100K active users)?

Some typical relationships:

A would be related to Q as being the answer(s) to Q. There can be multiple answers to Q. Q, A, B will all be listed on the same window with checkbox choices to show/hide Q&A or B or BOTH. Answers to Q can be associated with A or B (users can assign a blog as an answer but expect to be less often) Quantity of A will far outweigh all of them, with Q following and B the least.

I am leaning toward one table for Q/B and another table for A - BUT I don't have a good clear rationale for it. (Don't have enough experience to see things in terms of scalability, maintainability, normality, reliability, clarity, etc. and future impact) Maybe scalability and maintainability would be prioritized?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Having only 3 tables seems over simplified. What about comments? Users? etc. The site you describe is basically this site. Stack makes their database openly available to all. I'd consider that database schema to be a definitive answer to this question: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/gentle-introduction-stack-overflow-schema/

Comment: Yes, over simplified as I did not want to complicate the question, but just to deal with the basic issue of Q/A/B, one or more tables.  Added a few more columns/explanations to the question above.  I didn't realize STACK published its database structure.  I'll have a look!  Thank you!

Comment: One table approach is rather complicated.Your 3 tables approach will answer these scalability, maintainability, normality, reliability, clarity, etc. and future impact.In fact going into detail of each table may be they should further be notmalize.don't hesitate.